# Extracting data from Address field using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

[image: Table]

I am fairly new to using python in field calculator and could use some help.
I want to populate SitusRdType with RD or AVE or LN or ST or DR depending on the road type.  I also want to just have the street name in SitusSt.  Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: What software are you suing (QGIS, ArcGIS, other)?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you need a pre-defined list of the road types, since not all your values end in a road type. For ArcGIS, the following is a simple example of populating SitusRdType:

In the Field Calculator, check that Python is set as the parser and check Show Codeblock. In the Pre-Logic Script Code box:

```
def setRdType(myInput):
    lstRdTypes = [' RD', ' AVE', ' LN', ' ST', ' DR']
    for rdType in lstRdTypes:
        if rdType in myInput:
            return rdType
```

In the SitusRdType = box:
    setRdType(!SitusSt!)
You may want to add 'HWY ' to the list if you want that as well. There's probably a more elegant way, but off the top of my head this should work.

To eliminate the same list from SitusSt:

```
def rplc(myInput):
    s = myInput
    lstRdTypes = [' RD', ' AVE', ' LN', ' ST', ' DR']
    for rdType in lstRdTypes:
        if s.endswith(rdType):
            s = s.replace(rdType, '')
    return s
```

In SitusSt =:
    rplcType(!SitusSt!)

Again, probably more efficient ways to do it, but this should work. Always try on a copy of data first.

Comment: The first part worked great once I changed [SitusSt] to !SitusSt! thank you!  The second part just returned null values.

Comment: Sorry, forgot a return statement. Bad cold, fuzzy thinking. Edited 2nd function, should work now.

Comment: It looks like it should work but now it just returns the same values

Comment: Hmm, code looks good. Edited for a slightly different approach, try that. You could also skip the codeblock and do a replace() on each road type separately, but that's obviously a less efficient method.

Comment: Edited for slightly better method, checking endswith().